# Django1.5 and 1.6 compatibility with json

Tags: json, django

I have a view that sends back json data from events as described in Arsawh's fullcalendar jquery plugin. Using [this](http://goo.gl/pCbnvo) worked fine. But after installing Django 1.6.2 I get the follwoing error

```
Internal Server Error: /customer/todaysfeed/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 114, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/avlahop/development/django/rhombus2/rhombus/utils/decorators.py", line 18, in wrapper
    return view(request, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/avlahop/development/django/rhombus2/rhombus/customer/views.py", line 103, in todaysfeed
    json_list = json.dumps(json_list, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 369, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'namedtuple_as_object
```

What could be wrong? This is the code again

```
if request.is_ajax():
    doctor = Doctor.objects.get(user=request.user)
    try:
        start = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(request.GET.get('start',''))).replace(tzinfo=utc)
        end = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(request.GET.get('end',''))).replace(tzinfo=utc)
    except ValueError:
        start = datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=utc)
        end = datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=utc)

    entries = Entry.objects.filter(start__gte=start, end__lte=end, creator=doctor)
    json_list = []
    for entry in entries:
        id=entry.id
        title=str(entry.patient)
        start=entry.start
        end=entry.end
        color= doctor.color if doctor.color else "blue"
        allDay=False

        item = dict(id=id, title=title, start=start, end=end, allDay=allDay, color=color)
        json_list.append(item)

    json_list = json.dumps(json_list, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
    return HttpResponse(json_list, content_type='application/json')
```

EDIT: Found it!! Clamsy of me, i was importing an older version of json. Now everything works great just used `import json`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19390574/namedtuple-as-object-error-when-trying-to-save-model-django-1-5) should help.

In short, you've got a system simplejson vs Django-packaged json clash as mentioned in [the release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.5/#system-version-of-simplejson-no-longer-used)